# Connection refused after install xubuntu desktop on ubuntu server

Tags: server, xubuntu, ssh, 15.10

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 Server (64 bit). I tried to install desktop GUI on it.

Whenever I install the desktop GUI I got connection refused after reboot and cannot login using putty any more any idea why ?

I used

```
# apt-get install xubuntu-desktop xfce4 firefox nano -y
```

Then I rebooted then connection refused happened .

Comment: I've had exactly the same issue on 20.04. Did you ever solve it? I think it's because installing xubuntu-desktop turns the installation into a 'desktop' installation and a bunch of server stuff gets disabled